# .htaccess rewrite rule for complex url structures

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

```
www.example.com/category/news/article-name
```

I need to drop the `category/news` and redirect to:

```
www.example.com/article-name
```

I have the following RewriteRule working:

```
RewriteRule ^category/news/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I need to edit the RewriteRule above to allow for the URL below to be loaded without redirecting:

www.example.com/category/news/

Currently this URL redirects to www.example.com

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `.*` (0 or ore characters) to `.+` (1 or more characters) in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/news/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Now it won't affect `/category/news/` URL.

Remember to clear your browser cache while testing this change.

Answer (score 0):

Try Rewriting instead of redirecting, in this case you can call `www.example.com/article-name` which internally rewrite to `www.example.com/category/news/article-name`

please check.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^([\w-]+)$ category/news/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't work. I got an internal server error. However, this did work: RewriteRule ^category/news/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]